# How do I select a portion of a string using regex and put it in a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to make a script to grab a date out of a file name that only uses numbers in dates and not the words themselves

I'm thinking

```
$Date = $_.Name | sed -n "\d.+"
```

but theres no sed in powershell

Comment: What's the date format? `MMddyy`? Do you want to capture the date as `string` or as `DateTime`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, I know that the input gonna be Name-Date, so it could be John-02-07-2021 or  John-2021-02-07, but the output has to be just the date, 2021-02-07 or 2021-02-07.

Comment: Note that if the files have extensions, you might want to use `$_.BaseName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$Date = [regex]::Match($_.Name,'\d.+').Value
```

If you want to store the date as [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) for further manipulation:

```
$Date = [datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name,'\d.+').Value
```

If you want to use the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#matching-operators) operator you could do:

```
$Date = if($_.Name -match '\d.+')
{
    $Matches[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out you gotta work in reverse, find what ISNT included in your regex and replace it with nothing.

```
"original word" -replace "regex for stuff you don't want"
```

So I wanted only the date, so I said regex not numbers which is "^\d" and not dashes which is "^-". So it replaced everything thats not a number or a dash with nothing.

```
$Date = $_.Name -replace "[^\d+^-]"
```